# How to format data as plotly.iplot required?

Tags: python

This is the data I have:

[image]

I combined them by date:
When I use iplot, error occurred:

[image]

Comment: Please do not link to images of code or error message. Include the text in your question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass plot.ly a dictionary, like this:

```
py.iplot({'data': [xyz]})
```

What you put in `xyz` depends on what chart you want to make. See [Plotly's Getting Started Gide](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

The data could be plotted using `iplot()` as a bar or line with code below (written in `Jupyter Notebook` using `Python 3`).

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot 
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()

# Create an example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'issue_d': ['2007-06-01', '2007-07-01', '2007-08-01', '2007-09-01', '2007-10-01'],
                   'loan_amt': [91850.0, 348325.0, 515300, 372950.0, 753225.0]
                  })
# Convert date string to datetime
df['issue_d'] = pd.to_datetime(df['issue_d'])

# Create line plot
df.iplot(kind='line', x='issue_d', y='loan_amt', xTitle= 'Issue date', yTitle= 'Loan amount', title='Loan Amounts', width=4)
```

[image]

```
# Create bar plot
df.iplot(kind='bar', x='issue_d', y='loan_amt', xTitle= 'Issue date', yTitle= 'Loan amount', title='Loan Amounts')
```

[image]